# How can I make ResultSet as a instance of Collection?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have this QueryService function:

```
public static function findAllOrderStatus(): Collection
{
    $orders = TableRegistry::get('b2c_orders');
    $query = $orders->find();

    return $query->select([
        'shop_code' => 'm.mall_code',
        'order_id' => 'b2c_order_number',
        'ship_status' => 'status',
    ])
        ->join([
            'table' => 'malls',
            'alias' => 'm',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'b2c_orders.mall_uuid = m.mall_uuid',
        ])
        ->where([
            'm.mall_code' => MALL_ALPEN_OWN
        ])
        ->all();
}
```

I am getting an error of

```
Exception: Return value of findAllOrderStatus() must be an instance of Cake\Collection\Collection, instance of Cake\ORM\ResultSet returned
```

How can I make the $query->select to be a Collection?

Answer (score 1):

If you want instance of `Cake\ORM\ResultSet`, you can do other way round. Why don't you use the following way ?

```
 $iteratorObject = $orders->find() 
     ->join([
        'table' => 'malls',
        'alias' => 'm',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => 'b2c_orders.mall_uuid = m.mall_uuid',
    ])
    ->where([
        'm.mall_code' => MALL_ALPEN_OWN
    ]);
```

If you want to use `all()` and `toList()`, find it [Selecting Rows From A Table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#)

I don't think, `select` can convert directly to collection object. But, you can do other hacking way to do achieve your goal. You can type cast the Array as an Object when returning it. Something like

```
(object) $array;
```

If you want to do that, remove `all()` and type cast and return it.

If your array is multi-dimensional array, I found it this way in [Richard Castera](http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass/)

```
function arrayToObject($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return $array;

    $object = new stdClass();
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
            $name = strtolower(trim($name));
            if (!empty($name)) $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
        }
        return $object;
     }else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: i want to make it by Collection, not by ResultSet

Comment: Ohhh sorry, I didn't read your question clearly. Let me relook at again

Comment: @JohnDaleOcayaAndilDale can you check again ?

Comment: I see, I will try this.

Comment: this will give error, "instance of stdClass returned"

Comment: Ohh your is multi-dimensional array is it ?

Comment: If multi-dimensional array, have to do another way. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

In case that method resides in a table class, you should rethink its name, as table class methods that start with `find` can be used as [**finders**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods), and finders must return query objects.

That being said, if you really want the method to expose a collection compatible return value, then declare the return type as `\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface` instead, `\Cake\ORM\ResultSet` is an indirect implementer via `\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface`.

See also **[API > \Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Collection.CollectionInterface.html)**